# Workflow on 2010 platform not sending tasks?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, workflow, designer-workflow, tasks, workflow-tasks-list

I have a workflow built the same way on 2 different lists. One works fine and sends the 2 tasks associated with it, the other - nothing. The workflow shows as completed, but the tasks nor an email I added just for testing will send. I have the properties set to YES for SendDefaultTaskNotifications. I am out of ideas on what may be causing this. They're identical workflows on 2 different lists.

[image]

Working list has:

[image]

Comment: Is the second workflow published? Have you tried to manually starting it?

Comment: Hello- yes, it's published. The workflow runs, and shows completed, just no tasks or email sent.

Comment: I notice when I compare the 2 lists, the one NOT sending workflows has nothing under "A list of workflows associated with this list." whereas the one that is working shows all the workflows associated. Can I add them back in?

Comment: Yes. You can add those back in using the workflow settings on the List

Comment: Thanks, guess that's not the reason tasks aren't sending lol  ....oh man I'll keep looking.